# Get particular values in php from ajax serialize

Tags: php, ajax

Have input form with input fields and selectors. Want values from input fields and selector values with ajax to pass to php file and process in php file particular values

Part of html is like this

```
<select name="record_date_selector[]" ...

<input type="text" name="record_date[]" ...
```

ajax is like this

```
var values = $("form").serialize();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '__popup-window_ajax.php',
data: { 'clickedId' : $(this).closest('td').attr('id'), 'Values' : values },
dataType: 'json',
});
```

With php

```
echo json_encode($_POST['Values']);
```

get something like this

`record_date_selector%5B%5D=3&record_date%5B%5D=02.07.2013`

How can I get value of for example `record_date_selector`?

Tried `echo json_encode($_POST['record_date_selector']);` But this way is not correct

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your php file:

```
<?php
// Get 'Values' value and store as array in $output 
parse_str($_POST['Values'],$output);
// convert $output in json
 echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

and Get value from ajax response like this

```
response.your_input_name; //response.record_date_selector
```

Comment: Tried `echo json_encode($output['record_date_selector']);` seems working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For this query string:

```
record_date_selector%5B%5D=3&record_date%5B%5D=02.07.2013
```

You can use [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function to convert to an array.